# Moving django models into their own files

Tags: python, django, orm, model

In the name of maintainability, I moved some of my larger models to their own files. So before i had this:

```
app/
  models.py
```

and now I have this:

```
app/
  models/
    __init__.py
    model_a.py
    model_b.py
```

This works fine, but when I use manage.py to do sync db, it doesn't create a table for these models anymore.

Am I forgetting something?

Thanks,

Comment: What's in `app/models/__init__.py`? At the very minimum, I think you need to import the actual model classes from the submodules (though this might not be the most Pythonic way to do it).

Comment: Also, consider South instead of syncdb.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Models must be found in module named `app.models` where `app` is an app name. So you should write in `app/models/__init__.py` file

```
 from model_a import * 
 from model_b import *
```

#### In Django < 1.7

Note fron django 1.7 onwards this is not neccessary.

Moreover --- (that's what I had problem with) you will have to manually update `app_label` attribute for your models, so write:

```
 __all__ = ["ModelA", "ModelA1"]

 class ModelA(models.Model):
      class Meta: 
          app_label = 'your_app'
```

without it app will be set incorrectly by django.

If you are afreid that `from model_a import *` are evil you allways can set up `__all__` attributes in all modules.

Comment: Better to not use `... import *`, but this is solid otherwise. :)

Comment: I'd argue. This whole stuff would be in the models module if it wern't split into submodules --- so it won't do harm, and I'd rather not change __init__.py after I added new model in model_a (OTOH if OP uses single model per file it won't do harm --- but I always had multiple models in submodules). 

I know that import * is generally evil, but in this case it is better to use it.

Comment: What are the failure symptoms if you do not add the Meta/app_label?  Because I'm using Django 1.6 and I use this approach myself to split up the models, and don't see what doesn't work yet?

Comment: It is not clear which __init__ file i should modify, one in the modules or one within main project directory?

Comment: As of Django 1.7 you no longer need to worry about the Meta class as this has been fixed.

Comment: This drove me crazy, so for those who come after, in 1.10 there needs to be a '.': `from .model_a import SomeModel`. As mentioned here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#organizing-models-in-a-package

Answer (score 9):

You need to set `Meta.app_label` for each of the models to the app name where it belongs and make sure they are imported from `models/__init__.py`.

You can have a look here for more details: https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/CookBookSplitModelsToFiles